# delete duplicate element from List in a script Ksh

Tags: linux, ksh

I have a list named myList in ksh script which contains

```
columbia
endeavour
columbia
challenger
discovery
atlantis
endeavour
```

How can I get

```
columbia
endeavour
challenger
discovery
atlantis
```

I mean a list without duplicate elements because I need to use  it in a loop 
like that

```
for var in {myList}
do
echo ${var}
done
```

I don't want to have the same element twice.
Than you !

Comment: Pipe it through `sort -u`.

Comment: you need to show us how you are "delcaring" `myList`. I would recommend that you store it in a file. But if you want/need to have it as a code, then maybe `myList=(1 2 3 1 1 3 4 5)` esablishes you list, but the making that list will be painful. So use a file, do `myList=( $( sort -u < myListFile)) )` ; Oh yeah, you also need a `$` on a variable that is `myList`, so `for var in ${myList[@]} ; do ` might help. Good luck.